# Calculate pressure from partition function with separated volume geometric parameters?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, pressure, ideal-gas, inert-gases

How does one calculate the pressure from the partition function if it is specified in terms of three parameters defining the space of which the gas occupies, but all three parameters are not always seen together in one term called the volume $V$?

I know that in general pressure is defined as
$$
p = k_B T \dfrac{d \ln(Z)}{d V}
$$

however the partition function for a gas in a gravitational field is

$$
Z
=
\left(
\left(
\dfrac{2m\pi}{\beta}
\right)^{3/2}
\dfrac{1-e^{-\beta g m h}}{\beta g m h}
(V)
\right)^N
$$

which contains both the volume $V$ and the height $h$, where $V=A*h$, and $A$ is the area normal to the gravitational field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the first thing to notice is that in a gravitational field the pressure of a gas is not constant, but decreases with altitude. This means simply asking "what happens when we change the volume of the gas?" is not a well defined question; the amount of work done in the expansion is going to depend on exactly how we change the shape of the container.

We can ask about the pressure at the top of the container. This is simply given by
$$
p_\mathrm{top} = k_BT\frac{\partial\ln Z}{\partial h}.
$$
Note that you will need to expand $V = Ah$ in taking the derivative.

We can also find the *average* horizontal pressure in a similar way
$$
\bar{p}_\mathrm{hor} = k_BT\frac{\partial\ln Z}{\partial A}
$$

If you want to know the pressure at a particular height you would have to write $Z$ in some more complicated form that would allow you to parameterise an expansion locally at that altitude. Alternatively you could treat the gas as a series of thin slices which can exchange material as well as energy with each other, find the grand canonical partition function for one of these slices and find the pressure of the slice from that.

Comment: @ Is it correct to use the following logic: I define a penetrable boundary $B$ parameterized by height $z$. The total free energy $F(N,V)=F_1(N_1,V_1)+F_2(N_2,V_2)$, where F_1 is the free energy of one of the segregated regions, $N_1$ is the number of particles in that region, and $V_1$ is the volume of that region. We enforce $N=N_1+N_2$ and $V=V_1+V_2$. This leads to the following equation $\dfrac{dF}{dz}=\left(\dfrac{dF_1}{dN_1}-\dfrac{dF_2}{dN_2}\right)\dfrac{dN_1}{dz}+\left(\dfrac{dF_1}{dV_1}-\dfrac{dF_2}{dV_2}\right)\dfrac{dV_1}{dz}=0$. This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: what I am trying to say in the last paragraph is that since the pressure should vary only with height, you can consider a slice of thickness $\mathrm{d}h$, find the partition function of that slice and use that to calculate thermodynamic quantities. The only complication is that this slice has to be treated as an open system, using the [grand canonical ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_canonical_ensemble), whereas the partition function in your question seems to be for a closed system, using the [canonical ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_ensemble).

Comment: What if we needed the pressure at the bottom of the container? I am trying to find the pressure in a rotating cylinder of ideal gas and have a similar problem.

Comment: @JacksonBurzynski Hmm. on rereading the question I realise that it is not totally clear what exactly is meant by "a gas in a gravitational field", in particular what exactly the quantity $h$ is. To try to clarify the pressure at the top of the cylinder is found by differentiating $\ln Z$with respect to the position of the top surface and the pressure at the bottom is found by differentiating with respect to the position of the lower surface. You would have to ask the original poster exactly what is meant by the $h$ in the expression in question.